# Executing PHPUnit_Selenium

Tags: java, php, selenium, laravel

I Installed PHPUnit_Selenium and Phpunit , I'm currently using Laravel.

If i include Require Once, it cant be found , if i don't i get Class not found.

I tried to locate Selenium2TestCase and it's found under /usr/share/PHPUnit/Extensions

Question 1
How do i direct the code to The file i need.

Question 2
Can i execute the Functions only and get the returned value? Or i must execute the whole file

Question 3
How do i execute this , i plan to store extracted results in Database.

Thanks in advance!

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/selenium.html

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertTitle('Example WWW Page');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel isn't getting loaded.

try `class WebTest extends TestCase` instead.

Because this was tagged as php as well, please note this is only a solution when using Laravel..

There may be some further editing to do on TestCase.php.  You'd may need to extend `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` there.

Comment: Is it possible to extend a class in a class? like what you said, extend PHPUnit_Extensions_seleniumTestCase

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but you can chain them.  Class A extends B, Class B extends C and you would have C's method available to A.  So you'd have TestCase.php extend Selenium and I'm assuming Selenium already extends PHPUnit.